# WebSocket Javascript client not receiving messages from server

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

I've got a Java web application deployed on a local GlassFish 4.1 server that implements WebSockets to inter-operate with the web client. I'm able to successfully execute client-to-server communication over the socket, but server-to-client communication doesn't work for some reason.

The Java code that sends messages to the client:

```
try 
{
    String msg = ServerClientInteropManager.toResponseJSON(response);
    parentSession.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
    FLAIRLogger.get().info("Sent response to client. Message: " + msg);
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    FLAIRLogger.get().error("Couldn't send message to session " + parentSession.getid() + ". Exception - " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

The Javascript code:

```
pipeline_internal_onMessage = function(event)
{
    var msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log("Received message from server. Data: " + event.data);
};

function pipeline_init()
{
    if (PIPELINE !== null || PIPELINE_CONNECTED === true)
    {
        console.log("Pipline already initialized");
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        var pipelineURI = "ws://" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname + "webranker";
        console.log("Attempting to establish connection with WebSocket @ " + pipelineURI);

        if ('WebSocket' in window)
            PIPELINE = new WebSocket(pipelineURI);
        else if ('MozWebSocket' in window)
            PIPELINE = new MozWebSocket(pipelineURI);
        else
        {
            console.log("FATAL: No WebSockets support");
            alert("This browser does not support WebSockets. Please upgrade to a newer version or switch to a browser that supports WebSockets.");
            return false;
        }

        // the other event listeners get added here
        PIPELINE.onMessage = pipeline_internal_onMessage;
        PIPELINE_CONNECTED = true;

        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            pipeline_deinit();  
        };

        console.log("Pipeline initialized");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The onMessage function is never fired, even when the server successfully calls the sendText() method. Using the AsyncRemote yields the same results. The onError listeners on both ends don't report anything either. This is my first time working with sockets so I might be missing something elementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
PIPELINE.onMessage = pipeline_internal_onMessage
```

with

```
PIPELINE.onmessage = pipeline_internal_onMessage
```

Please refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) for more.